# How to get string in JSON?

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I have the JSON like this:

```
{"message":"[{\"file_name\":\"1464312906_84174_upload.jpg\",\"file_url\":\"uploads\\/tmp\\/1464312906_84174_upload.jpg\"}]","code":200}
```

How to get the string "1464312906_84174_upload.jpg" by JSON Expression?

Comment: I think you dont need a regex to do that.

Comment: I'm learning JMeter and I want to get that string for a POST method. So what should I do?

Comment: .... umm, parse the JSON ? Use json parsers!

Answer (score 0):

`message` appears to be a JSON-encoded array. So parse it and then access the property you want.

```
JSON.parse(data.message)[0].file_name
```

Replace `data` with the variable containing the object you showed in the question.